# Linux C process wait till copy of files completed (shell command)

Tags: linux, shell, embedded-linux, cp

I am trying to copy multiple folders and files from one folder (linux SBC) to another folder (USB mounted folder) from a process.

My process is completely written in C. The linux system is an SBC running YOCTO, and it doesnt have `rsync` available.

I used `popen` command for most of the commands like `mount`, `umount`, etc..
But for copying (`cp` command) I am not sure how to wait for the copy to complete.

I am using below format in my C code and it works (copying works)

```
system("yes | cp -rf " USB_DATA_SOURCE_PATH " " USB_DATA_DESTINATION_PATH);
```

I need to copy multiple files and there can be any number of files with dynamic names. All I need is a way to know that the copying is completed and is safe to `umount` and indicate to the user.

Comment: According to the manual page for system(3): "system() returns after the command has been completed".

Comment: Read `man 2 sync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in the comments:

1. `system()` waits until `cp` has finished, so you don't have to add any wait cycles.
2. **But** when `cp` returns the copied data may not necessarily have already been written to disk from the buffers. You can call `sync` explicitly to make this happen.
3. **But** `umount` already ensures the cache being synced/buffers flushed; that's why it sometimes takes some time until `umount` returns.

To wrap it all up, no need for an explicit `sync` between `cp` and `umount`, except if there are additional actions between and you want to make sure the data is synced even when the USB disk is yanked from the machine without being properly unmounted. In that case your best option is to extend your `system()` call:

```
system("yes | cp -rf " USB_DATA_SOURCE_PATH " " USB_DATA_DESTINATION_PATH "; sync");
```

to force `sync` independent of the success of the copy command, or

```
system("yes | cp -rf " USB_DATA_SOURCE_PATH " " USB_DATA_DESTINATION_PATH " && sync");
```

if you need to get the unchanged exit code of `cp` in case it fails.

Comment: @ Michael Foukarakis and @Murphy Thanks a lot.

I tested with HIGE files and it sure waits. I was earlier testing with small filles and was almost immediate so worried.

Comment: i am using popen command for umount to check the response.
Thank you for the extended command.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference to the command line itself; `sync` usually doesn't print any output, but it may alter the exit code of the previous commands when they fail. If you depend on that then replace `;` with ` && `

Comment: If && is added will the system command still be blocking? As soon as the copy is successful, the USB is expected to be unmounted.

Comment: The only difference when using `&&` is that `sync` will only be executed when `cp` returns successful. So simplified it's yes, it'll change nothing regarding the timing.